# How to map TextureRegion into Pixmap correctly?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make my texture region into a pixmap but by following the prepared method it is copying the whole atlas into the pixmap , so I am suggested to loop each pixel and map it into another pixmap manually

```
    Pixmap emptyPixmap = new Pixmap(trLine.getRegionWidth(), trLine.getRegionHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    Texture texture = trLine.getTexture();
    texture.getTextureData().prepare();
    Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();

    for (int x = 0; x < trLine.getRegionWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < trLine.getRegionHeight(); y++) {
            int colorInt = pixmap.getPixel(trLine.getRegionX() + x, trLine.getRegionY() + y);
            emptyPixmap.drawPixel( trLine.getRegionX() + x , trLine.getRegionY() + y , colorInt );
        }
    }

    trBlendedLine=new Texture(emptyPixmap);
```

But the texture generated is drawing nothing , which means the getPixel is not getting the correct pixel. Please advice.

Comment: the method trLine.getTexture() gets the whole texture for the texture region. if you just want the specific region use trLine

Comment: Did you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451787/libgdx-textureregion-to-pixmap

Comment: @MilanG Yes , I am trying this solution , but couldn't get it to work with textureRegion

Comment: @dfour thanks for the info , but I need to consumePixmap() method to map the textureregion into pixmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing your pixel outside of the pixmap by using the trLine.getRegionX() + x and trLine.getRegionY() + y . What you should have instead is:

```
for (int x = 0; x < trLine.getRegionWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < trLine.getRegionHeight(); y++) {
        int colorInt = pixmap.getPixel(trLine.getRegionX() + x, trLine.getRegionY() + y);
        emptyPixmap.drawPixel(x , y , colorInt );
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the obvious bug in my code , btw , I realise pixmap is very costly to achieve what I want , like erasing a polygon shape out of a texture