# How to convert gdImagePtr to base64 string

Tags: c++, libgdx

I am working on streamdeck plugin. Streamdeck supports showing custom images is base64 format.
I would like to generate an image using libgd and send the base64 string to streamdeck.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first render to a framebuffer (virtual screen), then capture the texture from that (because no direct reads on a framebuffer), then convert that captured texture to a pixmap, then get the pixels to a bytebuffer, then convert to base64.

Framebuffer
https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/opengl-utils/frame-buffer-objects

Framebuffer conversion
[libgdx TextureRegion to Pixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451787/libgdx-textureregion-to-pixmap)